# how can i use array index in Linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Class

```
public class SizesClass
    {
        public int Sizeid { get; set; }
        public string SizeNumbers { get; set; }

    }
```

That datas in SizeNumbers is like `20*20*30`
then i have a list of this class that i want order this by one of those numbers.

```
var orderByDescending = Sizes.OrderBy(x => x.SizeNumbers.Split('*')[2]);
```

but `var orderByDescending` turn into null and exeption said

```
The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

Comment: Give more code. What is `Sizes`? and the content of SizeNumber might not contain 3 or more elements after the split. gotta check for that.

Comment: Provide an `IComparer<SizesClass>` to the `OrderBy` and that will filter as expected

Comment: Your above code doesn't work since OrderBy expects a Column for Ordering not a value that you are supplying, it runs its own default comparison algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
var orderByDescending = Sizes.AsEnumerable.OrderBy(x => x.SizeNumbers.Split('*')[2]);
```

Because LINQ to Entities does not support 'ArrayIndex' we need to load  all the data into memory, we can achieve that using AsEnumerable() (or using ToList()) then we can do all the order by on the in memory collection.

Comment: Where is it mentioned that `Sizes` by default is not an `IEnumerable`

Comment: He didn't mention that but because what he trying to do is not supported in LINQ to Entites he should bring the collection to memoery somehow and then use LINQ to objects on it . This can be achieved by explicitly calling AsEnumerable() or ToList().

Comment: That's not the reason for failure, here instead of column expected by `OrderBy`, value is supplied, which is causing the failure

Comment: @PoryaDelnavaz consider using the linq query I have posted underneath, that will ensure that query will not break due to data / array index not available and similar issues